# Get row after last cell in tableview

Tags: arrays, swift, uikit, tableview

How do I get the last unpopulated tableview cell (Create a cell after all the rows created from an array)? I have tried the following method but that removes the last populated cell in the tableview:

```
if indexPath.row == dataSourceArray.count - 1 {
   //create total label
}
```

Comment: You should it in tableviewFooter.

Comment: @SatyenChauhan Thank you!